# Line up data spread across multiple Excel columns

Tags: excel

I have scoured the Internet and tried a billion different VLOOKUP formulas and Visual Basic marcos to no avail on this one.

I have 4 columns of letters and numbers (identifiers).  Some of the identifiers are duplicated in the 4 columns.  I need to line up the data in the columns so that I can see which identifiers are in multiple columns.  There are some identifiers in each column that are not in any other columns (each column had a different number of entries, so the identifiers do not currently line up).

I want it to look something like this (minus the ...s):

Column A..............Column B...........Column C..............Column D
R101...............................................R101........................

R102.........................R102................................

R103.................................................................................R103

R104........................R104.................R104.........................

.................................R105.........................

There are a couple of additional columns of data associated with Column A that need to remain tied to the identifier they correspond to in Column A (so the data in Column E and F should stay tied to the item the correspond to in column A).  The identifiers in Columns B, C, and D can move about however they need to to line up with their matches in A.  Honestly, all I really care about is whether values in B, C, and D are also in A.  I'm happy to use a macro.  The identifiers in Columns B, C, and D are also avaialble in other sheets of the same workbook -- I moved them into the same sheet as Column A because I thought it would be easier to make this work... but I could be wrong!

Can someone help me with this?  Very explicit copy-paste type instructions are appreciated!  I currently have the data organized into adjacent columns A, B, C, and D.

Comment: It would be easier if you provide the problem and the expected result. From the text we don't know if the example is the source or the expected result.

Comment: Any advice on how to do this without being able to use <table> tags in HTML or upload a screen shot?  Linking to someone else's example was the best thing I could think of!  I'll try to be more explicit.

Comment: So basically what you want is to sort all identifiers altogether but keeping each one in its column, am I right? So for example, if we add R100 at the bottom of column C, after processing, all rows would move down one place and all columns but C will be blank in the first row. If this is what you need, I think the only option is to use a macro...

Comment: Right, Andrew.  That's what I'm going for!  I just realized this probably also factors in -- There are a couple of additional columns of data associated with Column A that need to remain tied to the identifier they correspond to in Column A (so the data in Column E and F should stay tied to the item the correspond to in column A).  The identifiers in Columns B, C, and D can move about however they need to to line up with their matches in A.  Honestly, all I really care about is whether values in B, C, and D are also in A.  I'm happy to use a macro.

Comment: Could you not simply sort by col a, col b, col c, col d, and then add col e as something like counta(a1:d1)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure I have understood your question , but suppose your data in column A ranges from say A2 through A10.

In column B , starting from cell B2 , put in the formula :

=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A2,B$2:B$10,0)),"",$A2)

Copy this down till B10 ; copy the formulae in B2:B10 to columns C and D.

What this does is where there are matches in columns B , C and D for data in column A , the entries will be displayed , otherwise the cells in columns B , C and D will be blank.